# Broken Fn key - remapping?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xbindkeys

The `Fn` on my laptop broke. Unfortunately it did so before I installed Kubuntu, but I'm pretty sure that I've tried live booting Ubuntu here before and the `Fn+F` combinations worked.

Is it possible to remap the `Fn` key to, say, the menu key or right `ctrl`, e.g. using `xbindkeys`?

The laptop is a Fujitsu Lifebook A512.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a key-press will result in a scan-code which will be sent to the operating system. Not so the `fn`-key. The scan-code of the `fn`-key will not be sent to the operating system, it will be used in the keyboards micro-controller to alter scan-codes of other keys which are pressed.

Therefore you can not remap the `fn`-key in the operating system. Some laptops provide a possibility to remap the key in BIOS-settings, I don't know if that is the case for your Fujitsu Lifebook.Checking the manual for your model  didn't give me a hint, please browse your BIOS to find out if it is possible or not.

Comment: Thanks! I found no way to remap it in the BIOS... that's very unfortunate. I guess I could just assign the functions I want to a key combination...

Comment: Yes, I am sad too, but we can't fight against the physic. Normally a key produce always the same scan-code. In laptops , where the number of keys is limited, the `fn`-key is used to let some keys produce different scan-codes depending on the state of the `fn`-key to emulate more keys. This works  keyboard-intern.